# Expressjs Multer Error Handling with Array

Tags: express, multer

I am using multer's array method as a middleware for my post route and I'm trying to figure out how I can send the error callback from the `fileFilter` function in the multer options setup as a flash message when the group of files that a user is uploading contains at least one file with the wrong format. My current `fileFilter` setup achieves this, but instead of sending the user to a blank page with the `File Selected is not supported` message, I was looking for a way to communicate that to the route using multer as middleware.

Here is my multer setup:

```
var upload = multer({
    storage: multerS3({
        s3: s3,
        bucket: options.Bucket,
        contentType: multerS3.AUTO_CONTENT_TYPE,
        acl: options.ACL,
        key: function(req, file, cb){
            var fileNameFormatted = file.originalname.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
            cb(null, req.user.organizationId + '/' + uploadDate + '/' + fileNameFormatted);
        }
    }),
    fileFilter: function(req, file, cb){
        if(!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|csv|xls|xlsb|xlsm|xlsx)$/)){
            return cb('File Selected is not supported');
        }
        cb(null, true);
    }
});
```

Here is my route with `upload.array('fileUpload', 5)` `fileUpload` is the name of my file input field and 5 is the multer file length limiting feature.

```
.post(upload.array('fileUpload', 5), function(req, res) {

    //Configure Uploaded S3 File Path strings based on environment for use in DB
    var uploadedFiles = req.files;
    var s3FilePath = [];

    for (var prop in uploadedFiles) {
        console.log(uploadedFiles[prop].key);
        if (app.get('env') === 'production' || app.get('env') === 'staging') {
            s3FilePath = 'https://files.test-site.com/' + uploadedFiles[prop].key;
        } else {
            s3FilePath.push(uploadedFiles[prop].location);
        }
    }

    models.Blog.update({
        blogId: req.body.blogId,
        blogDate: req.body.blogDate,
    }, {
        where: {
            userId: req.user.userId,
            blogId: req.body.blogId
        }
    }).then(function(blog) {
        console.log('This is the blog ' + blog);
        var files = _.map(s3FilePath, function(file) {
            console.log(file);
            return {
                fileName: file,
                blogId: req.body.blogId
            };
        });
        return models.BlogFile.bulkCreate(files);
    }).then(function() {
        res.redirect('/app');
    }).catch(function(err) {
        res.send(err);
        console.log('File Post Error ' + err);
    });
});
```